# Sequelize querying inside virtual column like Laravel get attribute function inside model?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to calculate rank from user model where rank is just number.
example rank:

- bronze : 50 point
- silver : 100 point
- gold   : 200 point

and when user rank is 150 point it should be in silver rank. Can I calculate rank from virtual column to get the rank name with querying into rank table ?

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Rank = sequelize.define("Rank", {
   name: DataTypes.STRING,
   tier_total: DataTypes.INTEGER
});
const UserGameID = sequelize.define(
"UserGameID",
{
  user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  total_win: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0
  },
  total_lose: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0
  },
  total_match: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0
  },
  total_point: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0
  },
  rank: {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get: async function() {
      var rank = await Rank.findOne({
        where: {
          tier_total: { $lte: this.total_point }
        },
        order: [["tier_total", "desc"]]
      });
      return rank;
    }
  },
  status: DataTypes.BOOLEAN //false: unapproved, true: approved
}, { }
);
```

expected result:

```
user_id: 1
total_win: 2
total_lose: 1
total_match: 3
total_point: 150
rank: silver
```

but rank always returning {}

Comment: I do not believe getters support async